# WPF ListView Column of Text Some Rows Underlined Some Not

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I need to display databound data in a listview such that some of the cells of the same column are underlined while others are not:

How do I create a data template that will display different control types in the same cell? (Visual Studio 2013, .NET 4.5.2)

XAML:

```
<ListView Grid.Column="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Results.MyItemSource, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header=" " DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Caption, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header=" " DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=OneWay}" >
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

ItemSource:

```
public List<object> MyItemSource
{
   get
   {
      return new List<object>
      {
         new CaptionValuePair {Caption = "Caption1", Value = new TextBlock {Text = "Value1"}},
         new CaptionValuePair {Caption = "Caption2", Value = new TextBlock {Text = "Value2", TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Underline}}
      };
   }
}
```

Bound type:

```
public class CaptionValuePair
{
   public string Caption { get; set; }

   public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

Problem: The StackPanel is just displaying the typename of a textblock.

Comment: I don't think your second column can display anything. The `StackPanel` is an empty container. How could it show some Text? It should contain some such as `TextBlock` or `ContentPresenter`, ... you should update your code to reflect exactly what you have on your side.

Comment: @Hopeless: I started off trying a TextBlock instead of a StackPanel, but the bound object provides a UIElement for the Value property, and I found the TextBlock merely rendered the bound UIElement's type, not contents. So I hoped a StackPanel could do the job. Anyway, I've got a working solution (see post below).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a StackPanel, using an ItemsControl and binding its ItemsSource property worked.

XAML:

```
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=OneWay}" />
   </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Bound type:

```
public List<UIElement> Value{ get; set; }
```